# Change value of AWS Glue Job Parameter

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Is there a way that I can change the value of an AWS Glue job parameter in the job itself? Let's say I have a parameter with a key of --color and value of 'red':

```
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['color'])
color = args['color']
```

The above code will return 'red' for the variable color.

How do I change this parameter so that the next time I run the job, the color parameter is blue?

Answer (score 0):

You can set "color" as default argument for the job, so that "red" is used if no "--color" is given.

To change the default to "blue" you will then need to update the job definition. This could possibly be done from within the job itself if it is needed (by using boto3 and having necessary permissions).

Look for `DefaultArguments`:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.update_job